# What exactly are Tor DNS servers?

Tags: ubuntu, dns

I am using Tor for a while and I don't understand what exactly are it's DNS?

I have a few website that can't be open when I use Tor because it's DNS server can't find it's IP! Can't we change it's DNS or do something to find my website without using my ISP DNS server's? My OS is UBUNTU + Tor browser bundle with Firefox.

Can we saw what DNS server the Browser using with addon or something?

Answer (score 1):

Tor doesn't have something like an own DNS. Instead Tor uses the nameservers of the exit relay. As [explained in another answer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/26/88) your browser or another client send the DNS request to the SOCKS proxy (Tor in this case) and the request is than sent to the exit relay which resolves it. So the answer to a DNS request can come from an arbitrary name server.

When the IP of some websites cannot be found it is the fault of the exit relay. If you mention one or more websites and the exit relay, maybe I could refine the answer further.

Comment: Do you mean to choose the end node.What is your solution?

Comment: I'd like to know what website you're visiting and what exit you're using during this visit. This could help to identify a possibly misconfigured exit.