# How to prevent DNS Spoofing attacks with Tor?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, security, dns, https, spoofing

This question is an extension of [How does Tor handle DNS poisoning](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/7477/how-does-tor-handle-dns-poisoning?).

After having read [Introducing DNS Resolver for Tor](https://blog.cloudflare.com/welcome-hidden-resolver/) and [DNS security issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Security_issues), I am a bit concerned about the riscs of using Tor (Browser) in presence of DNS spoofing/poisoning or MITM attacks.

If I have understood correctly, following happens when visiting `https://example.com`:

1. *Tor exit node* resolves `example.com` to an IP, e.g. 5.5.5.5
2. End-to-end HTTPS encryption is established between *Tor browser client and `example.com`*.

Given an evil exit node resolves the domain name to a different IP address 5.5.5.7 owned by Mallory. Then the returned site still needs to deliver a certificate as response, which most probably is self-signed and not trusted by a browser root certificate authority. Hence I would get a certificate error in case of DNS spoofing.

Doesn't that mean, I am safe concerning DNS attacks, when enforcing HTTPS with Tor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You are.

I would also like to point out that your normal DNS server could perform this too, however targeted at *you* specifically. The Tor exit node does not know who is trying to access the website, just someone.

I would also like to point that you may want to use onion services wherever possible as they do not have this problem.

Comment: Thanks! The habit of preferring onion services is also a good tipp.

Comment: @cane_xmx3 Another thing I forgot to add: If an exit node did DNS spoofing it would be removed from the network.