# Why Tor doesn't support UDP?

Tags: circuit

Tor relays reject UDP packets except DNS requests. What is the technical reason behind that UDP is not routed through Tor circuit? Are there limitations with UDP protocol that it *cannot* be routed through Tor? Is there a problem with implementation design of Tor that it cannot support UDP?

Is UDP being connectionless protocol a problem? If this is a problem it cannot support UDP then how DNS requests are supported?

Comment: this is about 5 questions rather than 1, all of which are already answered on here on in the FAQ: https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#TransportIPnotTCP

Comment: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/8/how-does-tor-route-dns-requests

Comment: Next time, just use the search function instead of asking old questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, DNS queries are made via TCP - Tor does **not** use UDP **at all**, strictly speaking. The resolving query from the exit node - yes, it *can* be made through UDP protocol, but it's totally up to the resolver libraries and settings on the exit node's *host* - Tor does not deal with it at all. DNS service inside Tor itself - the one you're configuring via *DNSxxxx* directives - it's rather a stub, than something that can be called a full DNS service. And about routing UDP in Tor network - actually, there's no technical blocker to use UDP, it's just limited "by design" of Tor's architecture. It has it's PROs and CONs - but the limit is just an architectural one