# How to find onion address?

Tags: anonymity, onion-routing, dns

Hello I'm newbie to onion protocol.

Tor(Onion) protocol is basically consist of three nodes for my anonymity connection.

However, in this point, we have to clarify  **HOW TO FIND ENTRY GUARD before establishing connection**

In basic P2P structure, there is DNS server helping connect newbie to existed node and is publicized.
But Tor has no DNS  **so I was wondering how newbie find group of node for own anonymity?**

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Read what you wrote one more time... The title and then the rest of the post. Is your question clear? Is your question about DNS in Tor? A simple google search would have given you [this good answer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/8/how-does-tor-route-dns-requests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Tor project maintains its own directory service of relay nodes, which users of the Tor network download.  From there, the client software uses various algorithms to select which nodes listed in the directory to use for connections.

Comment: Thanks for replying :) If relay nodes are hard coded, how we trust them(they are may police or employee of government.)? and also are they fixed sometimes manually by tor project operator?

Comment: They are not hard-coded, but questions go in questions, not comments, so you should ask a new question.